# BulletPhysics - Set hinge angle explicitly?

Tags: c#, bulletphysics

A hinge's `hingeAngle` can be retrieved as a singular float but not be set explicit. I am simulating a door using hinges and need to be able to instantly set the angle to open or closed at will. How can this be achieved?

The hinge is created with:

```
const float mass = 10.0f;
BoxShape boxShape = new BoxShape(Door.CollisionShape);
Vector3 pivotA = new Vector3(-Door.CollisionShape.X, Door.CollisionShape.Y, Door.CollisionShape.Z);

door.rigidBody = physics.LocalCreateRigidBody(mass, door.getRotationMatrix() * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(position), boxShape);
door.rigidBody.ActivationState = ActivationState.DisableDeactivation;
door.rigidBody.UserObject = "Door";

var axisA = Vector3.UnitY; // pointing upwards, aka Y-axis
var hinge = new HingeConstraint(door.rigidBody, pivotA, axisA);
hinge.SetLimit(-(float)Math.PI * 0.25f, 0);

physics.World.AddConstraint(hinge);
```

and I am moving it with:

```
float targetVelocity = Door.OpenSpeed;
float maxMotorImpulse = 1.0f;
door.hinge.EnableAngularMotor(true, targetVelocity, maxMotorImpulse);
```

On each step BulletPhysics increases the `hingeangle` based on the `targetVelocity`. I'm looking to set this value directly, as opposed to indirectly by applying forces.

Comment: what code have you written to solve this?

Comment: @DanielA.White what would you like to see?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setMotorTarget() function?

```
void btHingeConstraint::setMotorTarget
(
    btScalar    targetAngle,
    btScalar    dt 
);
```

Is your desired behaviour that the door changes from open to close, in a single simulation step?

If so, that seems a dangerous thing to do, because there may be something blocking the door, and by hard-setting the door rigid body, it may be intersection other shapes.

Comment: I got the door to open and close by multiplying the hinges MotorTargetVelocity by -1 and locked the maximum and minimum angle with the SetLimit() function. It works but not perfectly. Can you suggest an alternative?